# read json using shell and inline python

Tags: python, json, bash, sh

Given the following json:

```
{
"project": "AndroidApp1",
"build": {
    "platform": "Android",
    "type": "App",
    "signing": {
        "pipeline-supported": false,
        "keystore": "release.jks",
        "keystore.properties": ""
    }
},
"automation":{
    "feature.automation.behaviour": "off",
    "feature.automation.branches": [
        {
            "branch": "feature-branch-name-1",
            "automation": true,
            "publish-fabric": false,
            "publish-ftp": false,
            "version-code": 19227
        },
        {
            "branch": "feature-branch-name-2"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I created the following function that can read a value from the json:

```
function readBuildConfigValue(){
if [ -e cicd.json ]
then
    jsonvalue=`cat cicd.json | python -c "import json; import sys; data=json.load(sys.stdin); print data['$1']"`
    echo $jsonvalue
else
    echo ""
fi
}
```

So if I do `project=$(readBuildConfigValue "project")` the project variable would be AndroidApp1 which is what is expected.

How can I then modify this function to return the json in such a way that I can in the shell script do something like `keystore=jsondata['build']['signing']['keystore']`

Comment: use `jq` you won't even need a function in that case

Comment: `jq -r '.build.signing.keystore' <yourfile.json`

Comment: @CharlesDuffyso doing `keystore='cat cicd.json | jq '.build.signing.keystore' '` results in "release.jks" (including the quotes). Is this expected? Should it not result in only the value of release.jks?